# Jquery duplicating child items in a list while looping through JSON

Tags: jquery, list

**Short question:**

Why does this duplicate the final item (shopping) but as the child of the item before.

```
var obj = '[{"id":1,"name":"Unassigned"},    {"id":4,"name":"Household","Children":[{"id":5,"name":"Gas Bill"}]},{"id":6,"name":"Shopping"}]';

function buildItem(item) {

    var html = "<li class='dd-item' data-id='" + item.id + "' id='" + item.id + "'>";
    html += "<div class='dd-handle'>" + item.name + "</div>";

    if (item.Children) {

        html += "<ol class='dd-list'>";
        $.each(item.Children, function (index, sub) {
            html += buildItem(sub);
        });
        html += "</ol>";

    }

    html += "</li>";

    return html;
}

$.each(JSON.parse(obj), function (index, item) {

    $('#dd ol').append(buildItem(item));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChatwin/cy4Lxq4m/

**Background**:
I'm trying to get the hang of the Nestable JQuery plugin. I've shamelessly pinched bits of code and managed to hack this *almost* working version together. Have I missed something obvious about the way the loop-though-children works, or is it something about the different types of list?

Comment: `$('#dd ol')` matches the `ol` generated for the children. Give the root list a unique id or use `$('#dd > ol')` to match only the root list.

Comment: That's so effing obvious! Thanks very much, no more hair will be torn out on this issue :)